# Angular Add css to noticeable-widget

Tags: css, angular

I am integrating Noticeable.io in my project and facing issues while adding CSS to it.
Here's is the code structure.

```js
<div id="notification">
 <noticeable-widget id="custom-noticeable-widget" popup-backdrop="false">
    <span class="material-icons">
        notifications
    </span>
</noticeable-widget>
</div>
```

and on inspecting the element is rendered as

[image: issue]

I have to add this CSS

```
#notification noticeable-widget::ng-deep #trigger {
  display: block !important;
  position: relative !important;
}
#notification noticeable-widget::ng-deep #trigger-badge {
  position: absolute !important;
  left: 13px !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

is there any way I can do it? I believe its causing issues of "#shadow-root".

Comment: to your parent component try to add  `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in `@component decorator` and go with the same CSS.

Comment: @micronyks tried but itsn't working.